# Opening the varbinary column in a popup window using contenttype

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I am making a file uploader using html tags. I have id, Name and Data in my table. Data is storing the contents of the file in binary format in a column of datatype `varbinary(max)`. I am able to successfully upload the file and I am also able to read the byte array back.

Code for upload at code behind:

```
    protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;

        using (Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    string query = "insert into FileUploader2 values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", filename);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                        Context.Response.Write("Uploaded Successfully!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

I am also creating a grid which shows me list of files along with an icon which when clicked will view me the file after reading the byte array. I have a JS function on that onclick which I am accessing through WebMethod at code-behind. Following is my code when user clicks on view icon:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void ShowDocument()
    {
        string filename = string.Empty;
        string contentType = string.Empty;
        byte[] bytes = null;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM FileUploader2", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        filename = (string)reader["Name"];
                        contentType = (string)reader["ContentType"];
                        bytes = (byte[])reader["Data"];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = contentType;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
        filename=" + filename);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    }
```

This code is working fine as well and correctly reads all the columns. Now after reading, I want to view the file as well in a pop window. How can I do so? I think I have to take contenttype to let it know what type of file I want to open and then use the bytes to do so. But I have no idea how to achieve that.

Comment: Do you know what content types that data might represent?  It would be easy to display it as a, for example, a hex string. Otherwise, you'll need to convert it to whatever type it might be and display it appropriately. I don't think there's a magic solution for this

Comment: Sorry. I am not getting what you just said. ContentType in my table saves the type of file I upload. for example text/plain or application/octet-stream